# Unable to use variable in query

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Baffled here: I am looking at a bunch of code written in PHP4 but running under PHP5 - the code (abridged) looks like:

```
$pid=(int)$customer_exists['pid'];//this value comes from an earlier query & does exist

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` AS p, `products_description` AS pd WHERE pd.products_id=p.products_id AND p.products_id='".(int)$pid." '"   );
```

This gets no result from the database.
If the first line is changed to $pid=28; or if the query is changed to just search one table then we get a result.

Echo out $pid before and after the query will echo the value assigned in line 1

(have tried many versions of the actual $query2 - all get the same non-result)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you cast $pid twice? Moreover if $pid is an int it's not necessary to put it within quotes in your query. Try to echo your query in order to see how the query is resolved by php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try changing this

```
AND p.products_id='".(int)$pid." '"
```

to

```
AND p.products_id='".(int)$pid."'"
```

theres a space after double quote and before single quote which you don't need.
Also, you don't need `(int)` here as you already do it in the previous line.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: and better compare with an integer, the field seems to be an integer here.Lets not loosely use MySQL's loose datatype comparison.
`AND p.products_id= ".(int)$pid  `

Comment: Thank you for the input - this made no difference I'm afraid

Comment: @Graeme - could you "echo $query2;" and paste in here?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `products` AS p, `products_description` AS pd WHERE pd.products_id=p.products_id AND p.products_id='3351' is what I am now echoing to the screen - this returns 0 rows although the value 3351 is in both tables

Comment: hmm ... query looks fine to me. Is there any mysql_error()? have you tried executing this query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Hi - see my edit - phpMyadmin was OK - there was some sort of screw up in the actual db - I have my sanity back now

Answer (score 0):

There are two points to improve here:

1. mysql_* functions are deprecated of PHP 5.3 and will be removed soon, so don't use them. Use mysqli_* or PDO instead.
2. This is a perfect code for SQL-injection (and that's bad). Better use prepared statements.

Example for PDO:

```
$pid=(int)$customer_exists['pid'];
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("`SELECT * FROM `products` AS p, `products_description` AS pd WHERE pd.products_id=p.products_id AND p.products_id='?'");
$result = $stmt->query(array($pid)); //note an array here
//Iterating
foreach ($result->fetchAll() as $row){
    //do what you need here
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php for explanation PDO constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by **Wbdvlpr** there is an extra space:

In addition, you don't need to concatenate the string anymore if the statement is enclosed with double qoutes:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` AS p, `products_description` AS pd WHERE pd.products_id=p.products_id AND p.products_id='$pid'");
```